# Mysql TIMESTAMP trigger doesn't work

Tags: mysql, timestamp

What I do wrong?

I have `table1`
On INSERT data to `table1` I have trigger:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2 (`c_id`, `date`, `product_id`, `price`)
  VALUES (
           NEW.c_id,
           NEW.date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
           NEW.product_id,
           NEW.price
        ); END


CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `c_data` (`c_id`,`date`,`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As result, I get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in date

MySQL version 5.6.28

Comment: Remove `date` and NEW.date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  from insert query. By default mysql will set date for it.

Comment: MySQL version 5.6.28

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND you mean: BEGIN insert into competitor_pricing (`competitor_id`, `variant_id`, `price`) values (NEW.competitor_id, NEW.variant_id, NEW.price); END ???

Comment: Remove ths  NEW.date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as well

Comment: move your comment to answer .... It works )))

Comment: Good to here that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `date` and `NEW.date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, from insert query. By default **mysql** will set `date` for it.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`c_id`, `product_id`, `price`)
  VALUES (
           NEW.c_id,
           NEW.product_id,
           NEW.price
        );
```